# vbscript update attribute xml

Tags: xml, vbscript

```xml
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="Account_Update" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
        <description>Account Update</description>
        <property name="name" value="Account_Update"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="E:\FileShare\XYZ\Account_Update\Input\Account_Update.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.readUTF8" value="true"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true"/>
                <entry key="process.enableExtractStatusOutput" value="true"/>
                <entry key="process.enableLastRunOutput" value="false"/>
                <entry key="process.lastRunOutputDirectory" value="L:\Data_Load_Jobs\XYZ\Account_Load_Job\Log"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="L:\Data_Load_Jobs\XYZ\Account_Update_Job\config\Account_Upload.sdl"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="upsert"/>
                <entry key="process.statusOutputDirectory" value="E:\FileShare\XYZ\Account_Update\Output"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.bulkApiCheckStatusInterval" value="5000"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.bulkApiSerialMode" value="5000"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.enableRetries" value="true"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="External_ID__c"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.insertNulls" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="50"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.maxRetries" value="3"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.minRetrySleepSecs" value="2"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.noCompression" value="false"/>             
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="60"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.useBulkApi" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

From above XML, I want to update value of `entry` node based upon `key`. Here is what I have tried to achieve that but its not working. Can you please suggest what needs to be change in the code?

```vb
Option Explicit

'On Error Resume Next

Dim xmlDoc, nNode, strResult, wshShell, ProgramFiles, objFSO

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.Load "E:\Avijit\process-conf.xml" 
Set nNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//benas/bean[@id='DE_OTC_Account_Update']/property[@name='configOverrideMap']/map/entry[@key='dataAccess.name']") 
nNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("value").Text = "NewValue" 
strResult = xmlDoc.Save("E:\Avijit\process-conf.xml")

Set xmlDoc = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
Set nNode = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues with your code:

- You have a typo in your XPath expression. Change `benas` to `beans`.
- The value of the `id` attribute in your sample XML is "Account_Update", not 
  "DE_OTC_Account_Update".
- For changing an attribute value use the `SetAttribute` property of the node object:

  ```vb
  nNode.SetAttribute("value") = "NewValue"
  ```

Also, `Microsoft.XMLDOM` is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Use `Msxml2.DOMDocument` instead:

```vb
...
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.Load "E:\Avijit\process-conf.xml"
...
```